# Can I see my troop morale?

Tags: mount-and-blade

In *Mount & Blade*, you're given the option to recruit villagers for your army. I've been led to believe that my troops need a certain level of morale if I'm to expect them to raid innocent villages, plunder, and pillage for slaves.

I would very much like to take over these villages and rule over them all with an iron fist, but I'm not sure if my troop morale is high enough to do any of that.

**How can I see my troop morale?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on "Reports" on the bottom of the screen while you are on the campaign map, there should also be a button for a report about troop morale.

This will look like this:

[image: Morale Report]

Comment: Well, now I feel silly...

Comment: Lol, don't. Mount and Blade is a very complex game and hard to figure out since the game tells you not enough how to play it.

Comment: Will the party size always be a negative modifier?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. The maximum size of your party depends on Leadership Skill, Charisma and Renown.